# Select statement to check for data in a column and if there is data to include it in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Here goes.  I'm going to apologize in advance as I'm by no means a sql guru (or even a noob).  I have a table formatted as follows:

```
Community Number   Street Address   Street Name   Unit Number   Account Number
123                5432              Oak Street    Null               1
123                5433              Oak Street    Null               2
234                456               Cypress Lane   C12               3
.
.
.
```

I would like to create a folder that would incorporate the street address, Name and unit number.  If there is no unit number, just create the street address folders.

The folders would read as such:

```
5432 Oak Street
5433 Oak Street 
456 Cypress Lane #C12
```

This is what I have for my select statement so far and it works just fine on the first two addresses.  Where I don't know what to do is when there is a unit number.  I'm guessing there is some sort of If THEN ELSE type check to see if there is data in the unit field and if so, append the unit number to the address.  If not, just use the Address and Street.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST([Street Address] as nvarchar(80)) + ' ' + [Street Name] as Address
```

I'm looking for a statement that will evaluate whether the Unit Number field is Null or contains data and then pass the correct info from the SELECT statement...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You could use [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST([Street Address] as nvarchar(80)) +
                ' ' + [Street Name] +
                CASE WHEN [Unit Number] IS NULL
                     THEN  ''
                     ELSE '#' + CAST([Unit Number] as nvarchar(10))
                END as Address
```

Answer (score 0):

use `isNull(a, b)` function, which takes two arguments, and returns the first argument if it is not null, or the second argument if the first is null.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Street Address] + ' ' + [Street Name] +
          isnull(' ' + [Unit Number], '') as Address
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are concatenating multiple columns and if any of these these columns are Nullable columns it is always best to use use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` functions on them columns to avoid unexpected null values in final concatenated values.

```
SELECT 
      ISNULL(CAST([Street Address] as nvarchar(80)) + ' '  ,'')
     + ISNULL(CAST([Street Name]   as nvarchar(80)) + ' '  ,'')
     + ISNULL(CAST([Unit Number]   as nvarchar(80))  ,'')  AS [Address]
FROM Table_Name
```